# The mass of universe at the time of the Big Bang

Tags: cosmology, universe, mass-energy, big-bang

The density of universe at the time of the Big-Bang was infinitely high. **Does that mean that the mass was also infinitely high?** ( the universe was extremely small at that time)

Comment: How do you know what the density of the universe was and how do you define the mass of the universe?

Comment: According to the energy conservation law I don't think so, except you see black holes as energy-consuming (not sure about that). If the energy/mass would be indefinitely high during big bang, it would mean that even if the universe expands (lowering the energy density) it still would be indefinite (And I think that that is not true...

Comment: I mean was mass extremely high? ( how could such a small thing could have mass?) I mean, when density increases mass also increases,isn't it? What is the estimated mass of universe at the time of big-bang?

Comment: What does "extremely high" mean? And compared to what? Nobody can make a scale that can measure the universe against the hunk of alloy that rests in an outskirt of Paris and that we use as a standard definition of a kg. It is by no means clear that "the mass of the universe" has any meaning, at all.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is important to note that the old Big Bang cosmology is no longer the most widely accepted theory. We include inflation into the mix in current theories. That said, there is an ambiguity in the definition of the Big Bang (you can find information on that in my question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132794/23473)).

If we take the definition of the Big Bang as coming before inflation, then we are probably referring to a curvature singularity. During this time, our best theories vary by a great deal in what we would expect to find. Many of them theorize the existence of one or more massive inflaton fields that eventually drive inflation. While we say they have mass, it is not the same as how a brick of iron has mass. The inflaton has a mass in much the same way that radiation or dark energy has a mass; there is a gravitational/inertial mass but not necessarily a rest mass. The mass density of inflatons is not usually volumetric, which means it does not scale with the size of the container. Furthermore, the mass in this case is used more as a coupling constant for the field. However, this is all besides the point, at a curvature singularity, the energy scales would be well above the range of most of our theories. Standard general relativity is not expected to accurately describe the universe at a point like that; we need a GUT and quantum gravity to accurately describe the physics of an initial curvature singularity. Short answer: No, the mass is not infinitely high. It is finite with a non-zero probability of being zero.

If we use the second definition of the Big Bang, where it occurs after inflation, then there is no curvature singularity. Under this interpretation, it is also common to treat the Big Bang as an era rather than a single moment, however we can look at the start of this era to answer the question. After inflation, the universe enters into its more regular routine. There is matter and radiation and it is very hot; everything one expects when they imagine the beginning of the universe (it's only $10^{-30}s$ old after all). The matter and radiation present comes from a few sources, mostly from the decay of the inflatons and quantum fluctuations during inflation. Since the universe is not confined to a curvature singularity and since the amount of matter and radiation is finite and generated by mostly decaying inflatons, the total mass of the universe is certainly finite. Furthermore, at the initial moment of the Big Bang era, not all inflatons would have decayed; the full compliment of matter in the universe is not yet present.

Now, there is one important thing left to consider. What do I mean when I say "the universe"? The possibility of the universe being infinite in extent means that the total mass of the entire universe is possibly infinite. So to clarify, when I refer to "the universe" I mean the observable universe. More specifically, because I'm a cosmologist and we like this value, I am referring to the region bounded within the comoving Hubble radius at the time of interest. This means we can further answer your question. Even though the mass is finite, I cannot deny that the universe was significantly smaller and denser than it is now. However, not only was the universe unexpanded (a small scale factor), the Hubble radius was much smaller back then. The energy density of matter is volumetric; it is inversely proportional to the size of the container. This means that, if no matter is created or destroyed, the mass of the universe now would have to be greater than or equal to the mass of the universe at the beginning of the Big Bang era (the comoving Hubble radius is larger now, which means the present universe can encompass more matter that was not inside it in the past).

This brings us to the end, for which I have saved the simplest (if not the most accurate) answer to your question. Your premise that the density is infinitely high is based on the following logic:

1) The universe has a mass $M$ now and a large volume, therefore a low density

2) At the time of the Big Bang, the universe was a singularity with zero volume

3) Therefore, the density is $\rho=M/V$, $V=0$, so $\rho=M/0\to\infty$

4) If the density is infinite, mustn't the mass be infinite as well?

Do you see the problem with point (4)? You used $M$ and $V$ to solve for the density, then you are using that to solve again for $M$. Logically, you can only retrieve the value you initially used. In other words, it's the same as the mass of the universe now (according to your reasoning): $\rho=M/V=M_{now}/0\to\infty$ but $M=\rho V=(\infty)(0)=M_{now}$

Comment: What evidence do we have for inflation?

Comment: @CuriousOne That depends what counts as evidence. It solves numerous problems with the old Big Bang model as well as explains the scarcity of magnetic monopoles. People thought BICEP2 results were a promising source of direct evidence, but that's become more skeptical as of late. Does better fitting the theories to the data than previous models count as evidence? I wouldn't say inflation is proven. But it is more accepted than the old Big Bang model, which has many problems

Comment: I don't think there is an actual problem with "the old" big bang. The problem is with general relativity at that scale. Why there should be a problem with magnetic monopole density is a mystery to me, since we haven't seen even one. It's not very intuitive to assume that something unseen exists just so we can make ourselves a problem that needs to be discussed away with an additional assumption. BICEP2 I would discount completely. Does model fitting count? Only if we are near 100% sure that the model is correct. Quite to the contrary we are almost certain that it isn't...

Comment: @CuriousOne the old big bang has the horizon and flatness problems to start with. And the magnetic monopole density (if they exist) is large according to the old big bang model. Large enough that we should see them. Whereas with inflation, that density drops to only a handful in the observable universe. General relativity was not the problem, the old big bang model clearly fails to explain things like the horizon problem

Comment: Both the horizon and the flatness problem are the result of extrapolating general relativity beyond its limits. General relativity has ZERO to say about magnetic monopoles... or any other type of elementary particle, while particle physics has next to nothing  of relevance to say about what happens beyond the TeV scale. It certainly can't help you with monopoles... we simply haven't found any. The only reason for any of these issues are breakdowns in our theories, not relevant experimental facts. What inflation is trying to cure is incurable without massive progress in HEP and QG.

Comment: @CuriousOne the uniformity of cosmic microwave background radiation could not be explained in the Big Bang. At that time when photons separated the universe could not come to thermodynamic equilibrium because of space time limitations. That is why they invented the inflaton field, to homogenize everything.

Comment: @CuriousOne Indeed as Anna v pointed out, the horizon problem uses the extrapolation already present on the old big bang model and focuses on logical inconsistencies. Whether or not it is because GR is insufficient is irrelevant to the point that the old big bang model is problematic and that inflation is widely accepted as a way of resolving many of the problems

Comment: @Jim: If you modify GR suitably, the horizon problem never even occurs. If you are willing to apply Occam's razor to this problem, the horizon problem is merely another indication for GR breaking down in the early universe. There is nothing unusual about that. ALL theories break down in extreme corners of the parameter space. There is therefor no need to invent something "new" to keep GR alive when nature tells us that it's basically not so. Remember the ether? It came from the very same corner of illogical thinking. There was no need for it, IF one was willing to modify Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: @CuriousOne But that still means that the old Big Bang model is not valid. And just as the ether was accepted until we could idealize a better solution, why not accept that inflation solves the problems of the old model better than any other current theory? At least until a better one comes along. But I repeat that all this discussion is moot. This site is for expressing the accepted views. Inflation is a widely accepted resolution to the problems of the old model, therefore it has a place here.

Comment: @Jim. I don't believe that inflation is much of a solution. One can push pretty much any inflation potential in there to get out any answer one likes. That's not even like the ether... it's more like epicycles, an ad hoc solution, the physicists deus ex machina. Having said that, inflation could make sense if we could identify a phase transition at that energy range trough high energy experiments, but I think we are far away from that data point.

Comment: @CuriousOne Indeed, inflation is very much like epicycles. Except, of course, it has a greater chance of being the correct explanation than epicycles does (thank you hindsight!). But the broad applicability and maneuverability of a solution does not make it any less a solution, it just means we should not use it as a standard that enables us to discount other potential solutions. Inflation was designed to take arbitrary, unknown, and possibly vastly inhomogeneous and/or chaotic initial conditions and make them homogeneous and orderly. Can we fault it then for being able to do just that?

Comment: @Jim: Something that can explain almost anything, including why the sandwich always has to land on the buttered side, is not a real explanation, at all. It's an intellectual copout. Not buying. Show me some real idea of what's going on, not a model that swallows an L2 function for breakfast to "explain" a few things that are likely to be the forbearers of bad news for GR.

Comment: @CuriousOne Don't kill the messenger. I didn't make inflation widely accepted. And regardless whether or not I personally believe it, I'm only here to say what one of the accepted viewpoints is. If you aren't buying inflation, arguing with me about its validity won't change anything. I have no better alternative to offer you yet.

Comment: @Jim: Take a look at Einstein-Cartan. It's basically just GR with torsion. Its popularity has waxed and vaned like the moon... but there might just be enough there to get people thinking a little harder about the things that Einstein may have overlooked even on the classical side of gravity.

Comment: @annav You commented " the uniformity of cosmic microwave background radiation could not be explained in the Big Bang. At that time when photons separated the universe could not come to thermodynamic equilibrium because of space time limitations. That is why they invented the inflaton field, to homogenize everything." I get the calculation of it from textbook etc, but I can't intuitively understand -- if at the big bang all distance is 0 why wouldn't everything in the universe be causally linked?

Comment: @ABC Does uniformity mean "causally linked"

Comment: @annav Doesn't it? "uniformity" "thermal equilibrium", don't they mean the same thing --- that's why as you said inflation is evoked because things need to be in causal link in order to have the same temperature.

Comment: @ABC not in my physics vocabularyBoiling water is in thermal equilibrium within its volume  but is moving all over the place.

Comment: @annav , ok whatever vocabulary we use, do you not agree the "horizon problem" is a problem because without inflation things were not supposed to be in causal links?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/cosmo.html#c5  "but the regions of space from which they were emitted at 500,000 years were more than light transit time apart and could not have "communicated" with each other to establish the apparent thermal equilibrium - they were beyond each other's "horizon". "

Comment: @ABC Essentially, the other physicists agreed with you. They couldn't comprehend how things could be in a state that wasn't causally linked at a=0. They also saw that it's in thermal equilibrium now. They also saw that it isn't possible for these two states to have been linked if the classical Big Bang model were correct. So they were like, "s#!t must have been linked once, then super expansion happened. Let's call that inflation. Then it stopped. Then it was now. Then I don't know what happened"